# Product of 2 measurable sets in new measurable space?

Tags: measure-theory

Assume $\langle X,\varphi_1\rangle,\langle Y,\varphi_2\rangle$, while $\varphi_1,\varphi_2$ is the outer measure of subsets in $X,Y$ respectively.

Now define a new algebraic structure $\langle X\bigotimes Y,\varphi_3\rangle $ then is it possible to give out the minimum requirement for $\varphi_3$ so that for all measurable set $E\in X,F\in Y$ would have that $E\bigotimes F$ is also a measurable set in $\langle X\bigotimes Y,\varphi_3\rangle $.

And if yes, may I further ask for the prove, thanks a lot!!